# Last row overwriting all the records in the result c# oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

We have a Oracle stored procedure which accepts table values parameters

In the Package description:

```
create or replace
  PACKAGE CRUD_FIELDS IS   
  TYPE tableParam IS TABLE OF "owner".tablename.columnname%TYPE index by pls_integer;  
  TYPE Param_Array is table OF VARCHAR2(400) index by binary_integer;
PROCEDURE USP_GET_BULK_FIELDS  ( pi_table_param tableParam, po_out_param out sys_refcursor);
```

Package Body:

```
 PROCEDURE USP_GET_BULK_FIELDS  ( pi_table_param tableParam, po_out_param 
    out sys_refcursor ) AS
  Fields_Arr Param_Array; 
  trRec recFieldType;
  trRecTable  FieldRecTable := FieldRecTable();
  n integer := 1;
  arrIdx integer := 1;
  BEGIN
  for rul in 1..pi_table_param.count loop    
  for fld in (select ruleid, addlid, code from  "owner"."T_FIELDS" where ruleid = pi_table_param(rul))
  loop
     trRecTable.extend; 
     trRec := recFieldType(fld.rule_id, fld.ADDL_ID, fld.field_code);          
     trRecTable(n):=trRec;
     Fields_Arr(arrIdx):=fld.rule_id || ',' || fld.ADDL_ID|| ',' ||fld.field_code;
       arrIdx := arrIdx + 1;
       n := n + 1;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (fld.rule_id || ',' || fld.ADDL_ID|| ',' ||fld.field_code );
   end loop;
  end loop;
  FOR i IN trRecTable.FIRST .. trRecTable.LAST 
   LOOP 
    open po_out_param for
   SELECT trRecTable(i).rule_id|| ',' || trRecTable(i).ADDL_ID|| ',' ||trRecTable(i).field_code FROM   Table (Cast(trRecTable As FieldRecTable));
   END LOOP; 
   DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS select * from Table (Cast(trRecTable As FieldRecTable));
  begin
  FOR item IN c1
  LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
   ('rule_id = ' || item.rule_id || ', ADDL_ID = ' || item.ADDL_ID || ', field_code = ' || item.field_code);
  END LOOP;
  end;
 END USP_GET_BULK_FIELDS;
```

When I execute this in Sql developer I get a proper result:
I execute in this way

```
      DECLARE
     pi_table_param owner.CRUD_FIELDS.tableParam;
     po_out_param sys_refcursor;
      BEGIN
    pi_table_param(1) := 154;
    pi_table_param(2) := 153;

   CRUD_FIELDS.USP_GET_BULK_FIELDS(
    pi_table_param => pi_table_param,
    po_out_param => po_out_param
     );  
   END;
```

I get result like:
    154,3,ABCD
    154,4,TRS
    154,5,EDR
    155,34,TRE
    155,5,EW
    155,34,RED
    rule_id =154,ADDL_ID =3,field_code=ABCD
    rule_id =154,ADDL_ID =4,field_code=TRS
    rule_id =154,ADDL_ID =5,field_code=EDR
    rule_id =155,ADDL_ID =34,field_code=TRE
    rule_id =155,ADDL_ID =5,field_code=EW
    rule_id =155,ADDL_ID =34,field_code=RED

I have written a program in C# to get the values, but im getting a weird output there.

C# code for getting the values:

```
     public void GetFieldsfoRules()
      {
        string connSt = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QuickStarts Instance"].ConnectionString;
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection oraconnection = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connSt);
        oraconnection.Open();
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmd = oraconnection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "CRUD_FIELDS.USP_GET_BULK_FIELDS";
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter oraparam = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter();
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter oraParamOut = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter();
        oraparam.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
        oraparam.Size = 35;
        oraparam.ParameterName = "pi_table_param";
        oraparam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
        oraparam.Value = new int[2] { 154, 155 };
        oraparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        oraParamOut.ParameterName = "po_out_param";
        oraParamOut.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
        oraParamOut.Value = 0;
        oraParamOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(oraparam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(oraParamOut);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter oraadap = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt_getRules = new DataTable();
        oraadap.Fill(dt_getRules);
        dt_getRules.Load(dr);
        cmd.Dispose();
       oraconnection.Close();
    }
```

The data table is filled with values:
155,34,RED
155,34,RED
155,34,RED
155,34,RED
155,34,RED
155,34,RED

The last row is overwriting other values. What's wrong here?

Comment: Hm... just a general question: doesn't `oraadap.Fill` return a dataset instead of a table? I guess you should use something like `oraadap.Fill(ds)`and then `dt_getRules = ds[0]`?

Comment: That gives the same result as well :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed It, Actually the Select statement inside the loop is creating the issue so modified the SP like

```
  open po_out_paramfor select * from Table (Cast(trRecTable As FieldRecTable));
```

commented out this part and added the above line:

```
    FOR i IN trRecTable.FIRST .. trRecTable.LAST 
    LOOP 
    open po_out_param for
    SELECT trRecTable(i).rule_id|| ',' || trRecTable(i).ADDL_ID|| ',' ||trRecTable(i).field_code FROM   Table (Cast(trRecTable As FieldRecTable));
    END LOOP;
```